# How to unit test assemblies targeted at different platforms (64bit and 32bit) in visual studio

Tags: .net, unit-testing, code-coverage, 32bit-64bit, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a visual studio C# project targeted at different platforms (64bit and 32 bit). I also have an extensive unit test covering this project. The nature of the project is such that , the assemblies it generates differs depending on the platform(not the fully qualified assembly name, assembly names are same regardless of the targeted platform). I now want to unit test these assemblies. What is the best approach to do this? Also note that I have to run test report (code coverage and unit test) on hudson. The current implementation have two different projects for two different platforms so that test run folder (the one with in /out directories) does not mess up with assemblies of different image format.  Please note that I am NOT expecting an answer for “how to unit test, perform code code coverage on Visual Studio” . My question is “What is the best and easiest way to unit test assemblies targeted at different platforms in visual studio”.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best and easiest way to unit test assemblies targetted at
>   different platforms in Visual Studio.

Have you simply tried running your unit tests on a x86 and a x64 operating system?  Although I should point out except for a small minority of things, the behavior of your code will behave exactly the same, two important exceptions are working with the registry and dealing with say unsafe code ( i.e. Handles ) which are platform specfic.

Honestly..You seem to already know what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually make the assemblies Any-CPU, if possible (of-course you may some 32/64 interop that means you have set the CPU target, but otherwise let them be CPU agnostic), and have the executing process decide on the architecture i.e 32/64 bit. That will rapidly cut down on the number of assemblies you have to test.

MSTest (VS2010) should be able to handle both 32 and 64 as it farms this work out to QTAgent(32).exe as appropriate. NUnit has 2 console types one set at any-cpu for running on 32 and 64 and one fixed at 32 bit for testing 32 bit assemblies on 64 bit platforms. Other testing tools may have their own approach or use one of the two I have described.

Coverage tools you could use in hudson:

1. [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) - a commercial tool (handles 32 and 64)
2. [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) - an open source tool (handles 32 and 64)

There are others that may be appropriate but I haven't used them so I can't comment on their suitability for use via hudson i.e. perhaps the one in visual studio can be command-line driven.